# 2013 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

As the Cross Validated community grows, so does the load on our moderator team. The existing staff is doing an excellent job, and in order to keep up the good work, they've requested a few more sets of hands. Therefore, the 2013 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://stats.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Good luck to everyone!

Comment: Can someone elaborate on why there is an election scheduled, especially for *two* vacancies? Are any of our (highly esteemed!) moderators stepping down? Do any of them feel stretched thin? I have not had as much time to visit the site lately; has the traffic increased substantially?

Comment: I second @cardinal's questions. If the workload is beginning to overwhelm the moderators (& I suspect it would eventually, I imagine it's *a lot* of work), that implies we need *more* moderators, not fewer. Physics.SE seems to be a reasonable model--it's about the same size--& it has $5$ moderators, not 3 going on 2.

Comment: @gung: The current moderators stay as long as they want to. Like U.S. Supreme Court Justices, they have lifetime appointments (if not quite as much power). ;-) So, if no one is stepping down, we'll have five. Five seems, perhaps, a little on the high end for this site, unless there are new developments that I've missed.

Comment: @cardinal, gung. I've understood according to [whuber chat messages](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold) that CV is adding two additional vacancies due to community growth. It also happened the same in GIS.se.

Comment: @Andre: Thank you! That is very helpful.

Comment: Andre is correct. The moderator team on CV is expanding as the workload increases. We are adding two more moderators to supplement the existing moderator staff.

Comment: Dear @Abby: May I suggest that for future elections (not just on this site), it would be helpful for the SE team to be a little more proactive about their communication. For example, it would seem prudent (and informative!) to see something akin to your most recent comment in the original community-election announcement. Cheers.

Comment: @cardinal, you're absolutely right - I've added some language to this announcement and I'll add a note to our election protocol.

Comment: @Cardinal I appreciate your concern. Abby's edit is on the mark: this election process was initiated by request. Nothing more should be read into it than what you see here. This year I have observed both a growth in site Q&A activity and the arrival of a much-awaited threshold in community interaction: no longer is it the case that a mod is needed to close or migrate a question--we have a critical mass of active high-rep users. I felt that giving one or two of these users full mod powers would help us all and alleviate the growing burden of keeping up with everything.

Answer (score 8):

After some searching, I found that **Yi Jiang's SE moderator stats site is still up and running** (and improved since the last election). In one location it conveniently summarizes much information about candidates' activities here.  Check it out at http://elections.stackexchange.com/#stats.stackexchange.